# File manager with integrated terminal (like KDE Dolphin)

Tags: filemanager, dolphin

KDE's Dolphin file manager has an integrated terminal

[image: Dolphin file manager]

Changing directory in the terminal also changes the directory displayed in the file manager.

Is there an Ubunty Unity or Gnome equivalent?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use dolphin in Unity or Gnome?

Comment: Only from an aesthetic perspective

Comment: Just for the aesthetic perspective, this http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/make-kde-applications-look-native-in.html still works...